# Can's use curly braces for it blocks in rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

```
it 'returns true for correct password' do
   expect(user.is_password?('password')).to eq(true)
end
```

I have this code for my rspec, but when i replace it with

`it 'returns true for correct password' { expect ...}`

it complains

```
syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting `end'
  ...ns true for correct password' {expect(user.is_password?('pas..
```

shouldn't curly braces equivalent to `do...end` ?

Comment: See the documentation for [Block Arguments](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Block+Argument) – it explains why `do ... end` and `{ ... }` are different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `do` and `end` are keywords which are not used in any other context except for blocks, the Ruby interpreter doesn't have trouble understanding it. But curly braces are used in at least two different contexts, firstly acting as block delimiters, and secondly acting as delimiters for `Hash`, which means you have to help the Ruby interpreter a little bit here when using the curly braces to let it know what context you want to use the curly braces in.

In your case, if you use the method syntax with parentheses, i.e. `it()` instead of `it`, this should tell the interpreter that the curly braces after the parentheses are meant to be interpreted as delimiters for a block.

Use this...

```rb
it('returns true for correct password') { expect ... }
```

instead of this.

```rb
it 'returns true for correct password' { expect ... }
```